# SourceSet with name 'main' not found

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'd like to Maven publish in my Android app, and I'm using kotlin-dsl for gradle files. This is how I'm trying to publish my code:

```
subprojects {
plugins.apply("maven-publish")

afterEvaluate {
    // Common settings
    if (isAndroidLibrary || isAndroidApplication) {
        extensions.getByType<com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension>().apply {

            compileSdkVersion(CommonVersions.targetsdk)
            buildToolsVersion = CommonVersions.buildTools

            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion(CommonVersions.minsdk)
                targetSdkVersion(CommonVersions.targetsdk)
            }

            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }

            buildFeatures.viewBinding = true

            tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
                kotlinOptions {
                    jvmTarget = "1.8"
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // Set up publishing configuration

    val sourceSets: SourceSetContainer by project
    print("project name: $name, ")
    print("project size: ${sourceSets.size}, ")
    print("project size: ${project.the<SourceSetContainer>().size}, ")
    print("project size: ${the<SourceSetContainer>().size}, ")

    if (!notPublishingModules.contains(name) && sourceSets.size != 0) {
        configure<PublishingExtension> {
            publications {
                create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
                    groupId = "xx.yyy.zz"
                    artifactId = "test"
                    version = "0.0.0"
                    from(components.findByName("release"))

                    val sourcesJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
                        val sourceSets: SourceSetContainer by project

                        from(sourceSets["main"].allJava)
                        classifier = "sources"
                    }

                    artifact(sourcesJar)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I always get this error: **SourceSet with name 'main' not found.**

As you can see I was trying to print the sourceset out, to see if it has any information or not. The size of the sourceset is always zero.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I use groovy with spring applications , I think you missing this in your code

```
sourceSets {
    main { 
        java { srcDirs = ["src/java"] }
        resources { srcDir "src/resources" }
    }
}
```

where you define where is srcDirs are .

Comment: Thanks, I think main should be auto-generated, I don't have to define it.

Comment: Maybe , am not familiar with kotlin-dsl , I think problem with this part I suppose , because with groovy I usually have to define it .